# How to get parent element html but not children tags?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I am not sure I gave correct title to my question but I want to ask to do something like:

I want to get HTML content of parent element. By doing this, this will also include HTML tags of children element but I don't want that. I just want children HTML.

For Example:

```
<div class="test"> This is content of div
  <p class="boring_class" style="borinhdlfj"> This is paragraph<br> content.<span><i>As you<br> can</i></span> see I have added <br> tag</p>
</div>
```

from above example If I use `.text()` jquery method to get div content I will get text only but not `<br>` tag. But if I use `.html()` jquery, this will also include `<p class="boring_class" style='dflkdjf'>....</p>` but I don't want that.

I just want html of children element which is:`This is paragraph<br> content.As you can see I have added <br> tag`.

How can I achieve that?

Final output should look like:

```
This is content of div This is paragraph <br> content.As you can see I have added <br> tag
```

Answer (score 2):

As one possible interpretation of the question:

> Get html of all children, including text [not in a children nodes]

You can use `.contents()` to include the text nodes of the parent (the parts that aren't in tags, eg "This is content of div") then loop through those to get either text or html depending on where it is, giving:

```js
var output = $(".test").contents().map((i, e) => {
    if (e.nodeType == 3)
      return $(e).text();
    return $(e).html()
  })
  .toArray()
  .join(" ");

console.log(output)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"> This is content of div
  <p class="boring_class" style="borinhdlfj"> This is paragraph<br> content.As you can see I have added <br> tag</p>
</div>
```

Note this includes all whitespace (newlines) which were not included in the question's example output, so you may need to remove these for an exact match.

Comment: That'll do the trick.

Comment: This is working but one problem is that it only works for parent having children. In my case, The Parent's children also include children.

for example: <parent><children><children> lorem ipsum </children> some text</children><parent>

and children can contain more children inside.

Comment: You'll need to describe how you want it to handle in that case.  Should the inner child include html?  should the intermediate (child of parent but also parent of child-child) be text only or also include html?   Your requirement is currently: top-level = text only, child = html.   So what should your first "children" give you?

Comment: In the case of `<a><b></b><b>` you've currently got a=text, b=html,  so how should it be in the case of `<a><b><c></c></b></a>` - the moment, `c` is included in `b` (as in your example where the `<br>` tag is included in 'b', the `<br>` tag is `c` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this in regular javascript by using `innerHTML` as shown below.

For more info, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

```js
const list = document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0];

const inner = list.innerHTML;

const noP = inner.replace(/<p[^>]*>/g, "").replace(/<\/p[^>]*>/g, "").replace(/\n/g,'');

console.log(noP);
```

```html
<div class="test"> This is content of div 
<p class="boring_class" style="borinhdlfj"> This is paragraph<br> content.As you can see I have added <br> tag</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean? His desired output is literally exactly what I'm logging to the console. (aside from the leading text that he accidentally included). The console is logging ` This is paragraph<br> content.As you can see I have added <br> tag` and his desired output was `This is paragraph <br> content.As you can see I have added <br> tag`

Comment: You are missing the `This is content of div` part - He wants all text including the parent dig text, but ignore the tags that are not `<br>`

Comment: Yeah, I definitely had a bit of trouble following the question, but I see now that you are correct. I got stuck on where he said "I just want html of children element which is:This is paragraph<br> content.As you can see I have added <br> tag." I think you've got a better idea of what the user is looking for. Honestly, though... parsing out that string is a lot easier than parsing out the user's intention in that question :)

Comment: @Stender - I misinterpreted the user's question. Thanks for clarifying. I updated with a fix that isn't particularly graceful & only works for `<p>` tags like in this example. @freedomn-m has a more elegant solution. Send all your upvotes his/her way :)

Comment: @Stender is right. i want to ignore tags that are not <br>.But one thng i forget to mention that children also contains children inside it. and can have more nesting.